# Change shape visible propertie of a slide range (VBA Macros PowerPoint)

Tags: vba, range, powerpoint, shapes, slide

I tested the following code to change the visibility of all shapes with the same name ("a") in each slide from the array...:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim osldR As SlideRange
Set osldR = ActivePresentation.slides.Range(Array(2, 3, 4))
osldR.Shapes("a").Visible = msoFalse
End Sub
```

But I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT6aQ.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim osldR As SlideRange
    Dim oSld As Slide
    Dim oShp As Shape
    Set osldR = ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(2, 3, 4))
    For Each oSld In osldR
        For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
            If oShp.Name = "a" Then
                oShp.Visible = msoFalse
                Exit For 'if there will only be one shape named "a" on a slide
            End If
        Next oShp
    Next oSld
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!